# Symfony/Doctrine Notice: Undefined index: 000*

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem about the flush on 2 linked entities (ManyToOne, OneToMany).

I'm on Symfony 5.1.

I just want to persist one "UserSavedCard" with many "UserCartSavedProducts" entities.

But I have an error when I flushed my entities and this error come to this file "in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php (line 3013)"

My function that throw the error :

```php
/**
     * Save current user cart in database for later
     * @param string|null $title
     */
    public function saveCart(?string $title)
    {
        $cart = $this->getCart();

        $cartSaved = new UserCartSaved();
        $cartSaved->setUser($this->security->getUser());
        $this->em->persist($cartSaved);

        foreach ($cart as $item) {
            $savedProduct = new UserCartSavedProducts();
            $savedProduct->setProduct($item['product']);
            $savedProduct->setUserCartSaved($cartSaved);
            $this->em->persist($savedProduct);
        }

        $this->em->flush();
    }
```

When I execute this code above But I have this error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: 000000007e86ae93000000003f3a2fbb
```

There is my entites :

UserCartSaved:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserCartSavedRepository;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserCartSavedRepository::class)
 */
class UserCartSaved
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="userCartSaveds")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserCartSavedProducts::class, mappedBy="userCartSaved")
     */
    private $userCartSavedProducts;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userCartSavedProducts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|UserCartSavedProducts[]
     */
    public function getUserCartSavedProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->userCartSavedProducts;
    }

    public function addUserCartSavedProduct(UserCartSavedProducts $userCartSavedProduct): self
    {
        if (!$this->userCartSavedProducts->contains($userCartSavedProduct)) {
            $this->userCartSavedProducts[] = $userCartSavedProduct;
            $userCartSavedProduct->setUserCartSaved($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUserCartSavedProduct(UserCartSavedProducts $userCartSavedProduct): self
    {
        if ($this->userCartSavedProducts->contains($userCartSavedProduct)) {
            $this->userCartSavedProducts->removeElement($userCartSavedProduct);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($userCartSavedProduct->getUserCartSaved() === $this) {
                $userCartSavedProduct->setUserCartSaved(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

UserCartSavedProducts :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserCartSavedProductsRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserCartSavedProductsRepository::class)
 */
class UserCartSavedProducts
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=UserCartSaved::class, inversedBy="userCartSavedProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $userCartSaved;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class, inversedBy="userCartSavedProducts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUserCartSaved(): ?UserCartSaved
    {
        return $this->userCartSaved;
    }

    public function setUserCartSaved(?UserCartSaved $userCartSaved): self
    {
        $this->userCartSaved = $userCartSaved;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Product

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserCartSavedProducts::class, mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $userCartSavedProducts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userCartSavedProducts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|UserCartSavedProducts[]
     */
    public function getUserCartSavedProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->userCartSavedProducts;
    }

    public function addUserCartSavedProduct(UserCartSavedProducts $userCartSavedProduct): self
    {
        if (!$this->userCartSavedProducts->contains($userCartSavedProduct)) {
            $this->userCartSavedProducts[] = $userCartSavedProduct;
            $userCartSavedProduct->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUserCartSavedProduct(UserCartSavedProducts $userCartSavedProduct): self
    {
        if ($this->userCartSavedProducts->contains($userCartSavedProduct)) {
            $this->userCartSavedProducts->removeElement($userCartSavedProduct);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($userCartSavedProduct->getProduct() === $this) {
                $userCartSavedProduct->setProduct(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running doctrine:schema:validate to see if your schema is correct

Comment: Hello, I have already tried and everything is "OK".

Answer (score 0):

I've run into an issue getting the same error, and in my case is that I was storing the entity object into a session and trying to flush it "as is" after retrieval. Regardless I could retrieve and dump the object and everything seemed fine (until flush), I was told that the EM lost management of the contents. So, to get management back, I had to retrieve every single id of every component of the stored object via its own getter, and then via find, retrieve them all and set them again into a new entity instance.